Win32: SwapBuffers() throws an exception on window resize
I am writing a win32 app that uses OpenGL. I want the window to continually update while it is being resized. My rendering code is in my main loop and DefWindowProc() enters a loop on resize, so my main loop code doesn't update the window. I put my rendering code in the WM_SIZE case to work around this, but whenever I resize the window using the corners an exception is thrown (resizing use the edges works fine).
My windowProc
LRESULT CALLBACK windowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_SIZE:
        windowWidth  = LOWORD(lParam);
        windowHeight = HIWORD(lParam);
        glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        SwapBuffers(dc);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

If I comment out SwapBuffers(dc); the error does not occur.
Here is the exception thrown:
Exception thrown at 0x0000024416BFFEAE in Win32OpenGL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000002441DCF5000.
What I have tried:

I put the rendering code in a WM_PAINT case.
I have tried using PeekMessage() instead of GetMessage() in hope that the main loop would continue on resize.
I have googled around. All the solutions I tried didn't fix the problem.

EDIT:
The Microsoft docs for SwapBuffers() states:

With multithread applications, flush the drawing commands in any other threads drawing to the same window before calling SwapBuffers.

Does the windowProc run on another thread and thus cause the problem? What does "flush the drawing commands" mean?
EDIT 2 + Solution:
Overall solution:
Disable the nahimic service.
Solution Explanation:
I tried to see if GLFW also had this problem, so I put the render code and glfwSwapBuffers() in framebuffer_size_callback(). Problem persisted there as well.
I then tried this with a Dear IMGUI window with the glfw and opengl backend. Problem persisted there as well.
I came across this imgui github issue:
https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/3321
It was extremely informative, and overall, the Nahimic service, an audio driver(nothing to-do with graphics and window resizing), is extremely buggy and causes the crash.

Where is dc initialized? Does it crash the first time that code is called?

@RetiredNinja dc is initialized in an init function I wrote and is a global variable. It is set using dc = GetDC(hwnd);. It only crashes in that switch case on a resize by grabbing the corner. I call SwapBuffers();  in the main loop and everything works fine there.

Does it still crash if you don't use a cached device context?

@RetiredNinja How would I do that?

@Zachaaaa By calling GetDC when you need a display context instead of storing one in a global variable

and ReleaseDC when you're done with it.

@RetiredNinja Been a long time since I've done any Win32 programming

@RetiredNinja @john I need the DC for the entire duration of the program. The program will be rendered entirely through OpenGL. I have called ReleaseDC on close. Are you saying that I use GetDC() on every frame? Wouldn't that lead to massive performance problems?

I don't know why folks are recommending against storing a DC for the lifetime of a window, but getting a DC is cheap, and a DC is a tiny structure.

@Zachaaaa Do you have a small fully reproducing project? How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

Wouldn't that lead to massive performance problems? Profile the code both ways to see if its a massive performance problem.  Do not guess.  Guessing results in bad code.  If you don't measure the performance, you do not know if caching the DC is a big win or just made bad code (i.e., an unnecessary global variable in this case) on the basis of folklore and superstition.  Compiler optimizers are amazing, and defy common-sensical (albeit premature) optimization.

@IInspectable I'm just recommending some troubleshooting steps to try and narrow down the problem. A cached DC is usually not a problem, but maybe here it is. The only way to know for sure is to try something else.

@Zachaaaa You may assume it is a massive performance problem but it is unlikely to be one. Every Windows program I've ever written calls GetDC/ReleaseDC or BeginPaint/EndPaint every time it draws and it has never been a hotspot for me to worry about. Aim for simple code that works correctly, profile it, and then you know what you might need to try and optimize.

GetDC returns a device context for the client area of a window.  When a window is resized, the client area changes.  (Other events might also necessitate the need for a new DC, like changing the screen resolution, color format, etc.)  Generally speaking, these DCs are for temporary use and not intended to be held indefinitely.
[There are private DCs for windows (CS_OWNDC) and window classes (CS_CLASSDC).  In the old days, the total number of DCs was pretty limited, so private DCs were discouraged.  Using a private DC can seem convenient, but they are not necessary.  I've never seen anyone use one in a product.]
Your best bet is to use GetDC and ReleaseDC each time you need to paint the window.  There's a lot of message traffic going on during a "live" resizing of a window.  You're not going to notice the overhead of grabbing a fresh DC for each repaint.
In fact, I wouldn't even bother with WM_SIZE.  Just query the window (or client area) size in the WM_PAINT handler and render the frame out there (at least for dealing with the sizing loop).

I tried that. Issue is was still there. I found the issue and edited the question with the resolution.
